# Passing arguments to java web service methode from android app

Tags: java, android, web-services

I want to execute java web service method from android app. My web service method signature looks like:

```
public String getData(String category) throws Exception
```

The method returns string and accepts a string as argument.

I have executed the method from google chrome's address bar as:

```
http://localhost:8080/JsonWebService/services/JsonWebService/getData?category=Marketing
```

Here getData is the name of the method and Marketing is the argument to that method. From explorer it works fine.

But when I add the same url to android app's httppost request it fails saying wrong number of arguments. My android app code is:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.7:8080/JsonWebService/services/JsonWebService/getData?category=Marketing");
HttpResponse httpres = httpClient.execute(post);
```

Please Note: Here 192.168.1.7 is required as I am executing the app directly on the device and hence I am not using localhost.

A non argument method executes correctly from android app also.
But when argument is inserted in the url why it fails saying wrong number of arguments in android app and how it executes correctly in google chrome on PC. Please help... Thanks...

I am adding the code here. My java web service code is as follows:

```
public class JsonWebService {
    @POST
    @Path("getData")
    public String getData(String category) throws Exception {
        JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject();
        String Email = "";
        String Name = "";
        String receivedCat = "";
        boolean status = false;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/admindb","root","");
            java.sql.PreparedStatement query = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM sample WHERE Category =" + "'" + category + "'" + ";");
            ResultSet result = query.executeQuery();

            while(result.next()){
                receivedCat = result.getString("Category");
                Name = result.getString("Name");
                Email = result.getString("Email");
            }
            if(receivedCat.equals(category)){
                status = true;
                jsonData.put("Name",Name);
                jsonData.put("Email", Email);
                jsonData.put("status", status);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return jsonData.toString();
}
```

My android client code looks as follows:

```
btnCategory = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
txtCategory = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
gridV = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
txtName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
txtEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

btnCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Thread netThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    final JSONObject receivedJson;// = new JSONObject();
                    String URL = "http://192.168.1.7:8080/JsonWebService/services/JsonWebService/getData?category=Marketing?";
                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
                    HttpResponse httpres = httpClient.execute(post);
                    HttpEntity entity = httpres.getEntity();                
                    String json = EntityUtils.toString(entity).toString();
                    String parts[] = json.split("<ns:return>");
                    parts = parts[1].split("</ns:return>");
                    String jsonPart = parts[0];
                    receivedJson = new JSONObject(jsonPart);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            txtName.setText(receivedJson.getString("Name"));
                            txtEmail.setText(receivedJson.getString("Email"));
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){                     
                        }
                    }
                };
            netThread.start();
            }
        });
}
```

The problem is in the java client in String URL, which is the string of URL that calls the java web service method. Please help me...

Comment: it´s a get request, don´t use post. browse a url in the browser is a get request. Instead of 'new HttpPost' use 'new HttpGet'

Comment: I did that but same problem. It executes from chrome but not from android app. Please help...

Comment: Pls let me see the code you executed

Comment: I have modified the question and inserted the complete code. Please explain why the URL I am using is not working.

Comment: I even used HttpGet in client and modified the web service with @GET also but problem is same both way.

Comment: In your code I still can see the post